# looking for a command to tentatively execute a command based on criteria

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am looking for a command (or way of doing) the following:

```
echo -n 6 | doif -criteria "isgreaterthan 4" -command 'do some stuff'
```

The echo part would obviously come from a more complicated string of bash commands. Essentially I am taking a piece of text from each line of a file and if it appears in another set of files more than x (say 100) then it will be appended to another file.

Is there a way to perform such trickery with awk somehow? Or is there another command.. I'm hoping that there is some sort of xargs style command to do this in the sense that the -I% portion would be the value with which to check the criteria and whatever follows would be the command to execute.

Thanks for thy insight.

Comment: why do you want a special command (with pipe)? there are builtins in bash to do numerical comparison.

Comment: I'm building a string of commands to take an aggregate sums of groups of data and if the sum breaks a threshold then an operation is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, though I don't see the reason why you would do that...

```
function doif
{
  read val1
  op=$1
  val2="$2"
  shift 2
  if [ $val1 $op "$val2" ]; then
    "$@"
  fi
}

echo -n 6 | doif -gt 3 ls /
```

Comment: cool, I will give this a try and report back.. care to extrapolate on your lack of understanding my reasoning?

Comment: `var=\`echo -n 6\`.` and then you can use `if`.

Comment: I'll give that format a shot, however I like having it in a function like that as it makes it more bash like to pipe to other places.

Answer (score 0):

```
if test 6 -gt 4; then
 # do some stuff
fi
```

or

```
if test $( echo 6 ) -gt 4; then : ;fi
```

or

```
output=$( some cmds that generate text)
# this will be an error if $output is ill-formed
if test "$output" -gt 4; then : ; fi
```

Comment: I'm disappointed that the tone of my question indicated to you that I do not understand the basic semantics of if statements.